# How can I determine the type of a variable when it is not given?

Tags: scala, types

Assume, we have something like:

```
val x = "foo".charAt(0)
```

and let us further assume, we do not know the return type of the method `charAt(0)` (which is, of course, described in the Scala API). Is there a way, we can find out, which type the variable `x` has after its definition and when it is not declared explicitly?

**UPDATE 1:**
My initial question was not precise enough: I would like to know (for debugging reasons) what type the variable has. Maybe there is some compiler option to see what type the variable get declared to by Scala's type inference ?

Comment: It would be hard to answer this question without some additional information. What do you mean by "determine the type"? To do something with it at compile-time? At run-time? Do you need the _type_, or is the `java.lang.Class` good enough? Can you use Scala 2.10?

Comment: This kind of "typeof" thing usually indicates generally crappiness of your code, you should structure your code so that polymorphism naturally takes care of this..

Comment: @TravisBrown You are right, my question is not precise enough. I would like to know (for debugging reasons) what type the variable has. Maybe there is some compiler option to see what type the variable get declared to by Scala's type inference ?

Comment: I would just hover over it and press Ctrl in the IDE of your choice

Comment: John, could you edit the additional info from your comment inside the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have the following in a source file named `Something.scala`:

```
object Something {
  val x = "foo".charAt(0)
}
```

You can use the `-Xprint:typer` compiler flag to see the program after the compiler's `typer` phase:

```
$ scalac -Xprint:typer Something.scala
[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: Something.scala
package <empty> {
  final object Something extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object Something = {
      Something.super.this();
      ()
    };
    private[this] val x: Char = "foo".charAt(0);
    <stable> <accessor> def x: Char = Something.this.x
  }
}
```

You could also use `:type` in the REPL:

```
scala> :type "foo".charAt(0)
Char

scala> :type "foo".charAt _
Int => Char
```

Your IDE may also provide a nicer way to get this information, as Luigi Plinge points out in a comment above.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, this helped me a lot (both variants) !

Answer (score 3):

Use this method for problem:

```
x.getClass
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easier version of Travis first alternative:

```
dcs@dcs-132-CK-NF79:~/tmp$ scala -Xprint:typer -e '"foo".charAt(0)'
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // scalacmd8174377981814677527.scala
package <empty> {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(argv: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val args: Array[String] = argv;
      {
        final class $anon extends scala.AnyRef {
          def <init>(): anonymous class $anon = {
            $anon.super.<init>();
            ()
          };
          "foo".charAt(0)
        };
        {
          new $anon();
          ()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel for providing additional information. You use a Scala option, where can I read about all Scala Options ? I could only find a manual page for the Scala compiler, not for the Interpreter.

Comment: The easiest way to see what the compiler et al support is from the command line. `scala -help` or `scalac -help` to see the "normal" options, then `scalac -X` to see "advanced" options and `scalac -Y` to see "private" options.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [IntelliJIDEA](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Show+Type+Info+Action), to show Type Info action in Editor, navigate to the value and press `Alt` + `=` for Windows and `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` for Mac:

[image]

I find it very handy when writing code.